# I want to replace the old 500GB HDD with a 256GB SSD. What is the simple way to this?

Tags: ssd

Can I just physically remove the HDD and connect the SSD in its place (and then do a new install of Ubuntu)?

Sony Vaio laptop
8GB RAM
Old HDD is 500GB
Nothing on the old HDD is important

Comment: Do you think there is a reason you can not do a new install?

Comment: Yes you can! Why not?

Comment: is "yes" all you needed to see?

Comment: Response to David, user68186 and Rinzwind: The reason I ask is that I don't know if a new SSD would need formatting in some way. If "yes" means that I don't need to worry about this, I'm more than grateful for your responses!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just connect the cable to the new SSD and it will be fine. You don't need to format the SSD before installing Ubuntu because the Ubuntu installer will do the formatting for you, however your options of choosing partition sizes are limited with automatic installation. This is why many people choose to do manual partitioning of the disk. The manual partitioning option of the Ubuntu installer does not require formatting the disk before installing Ubuntu on it either.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @MFS If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color from gray  to green.